# 3D objects for Kinect application

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, kinect

Currently i am working on kinect Virtual Jewel shop app. In which user can able to choose the jewels and check how it looks .
The App started with 2d images where it does not look realistic . 
so can any one suggest your ideas for the following queries.

How to make the 2D images realistic without going forward for 3D?
I choose 3d for fitting the jewels with neck , we can skew and rotate the images in 3D. Whether the same thing can be accomplished by 2d? if so how can we do it.

For going forward with 3d is there any tool available to convert the 2D images into 3D?

I am zero and new to 3D objects, pls tell me how we can sit the 3D object in skeleton data. is there any format available in 3D ?

The  current application is in wpf 4.0 so How can we use the 3D object in WPF ??

Comment: This would be better in XNA/Unity, please see http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34676/should-i-use-xna-or-unity-to-build-a-video-game on which you should choose'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can look realistic without 3D. But you can generate a 3D mesh with the form of the jewel.
(See this to get the idea http://fenicsproject.org/_images/hollow_cylinder.png ).

And put your 2D images like a texture on the mesh.

Check the riemers tutorials.
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Textures.php